# shipp-sliding-menu android slider error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, menu, slide

I am trying to implement facebook like slider, and i am planning to user below opensource code

https://github.com/leonardosalles/shipp-sliding-menu

but after i integrate, i created a sample activity

as per the code guide, in the

> PrincipalActivity.java

```
//intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity2.class);
```

if it try giving my class, i get below error

cannot find symbol constructor Intent(,java.lang.Class)

here is my activity class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SampleFirstTest extends Activity

{
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

}
```

please Help me to resolve the issue, i am new to android..

Answer (score 0):

add SampleFirstTest in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes, i missed that step, but after added the class name i still get error..

Comment: cannot find symbol constructor Intent(<anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener>,java.lang.Class<org.shipp.activity.SampleFirstTest>) --- This is the exact error i get